Backtesting an Interest Rate Swap Strategy
I'm trying to value a forward starting interest rate swap and calculate the PnL of my trade. Say these are the zero rates:
On day T



Year
Rate




1
1.1


2
1.3


3
1.5



On day T+1



Year
Rate




1
1.08


2
1.29


3
1.48



Say that on day T, I receive a 2Y1Y (2 year forward 1 year rate) swap.
Using the zero rates above, on day T, this would be traded at:
((1 + .015)^3 / (1 + .013)^2) - 1 = 1.9%.
In order to calculate my PnL from this receiver after one day, would it be correct to now calculate the (1 year 364 day forward 1 year rate) swap and compare the rate? So, specifically, I need to track the IRS which now has a forward that is 1 day less, or the 1 year 364 day forward  year rate.
Therefore, the rate of my IRS on day T+1 would be:
forward_years = 2 - (1/365) = 1.997
end_years = 3 - (1/365) = 2.997
((1 + .0148)^(2.997)  / (1 + .0129) ^ (1.997))  = 1.8%
Therefore, my PnL for having a $1000 DV01 position would be 1000 * (1.9 - 1.8) * 100 = 10,000 dollars.
Is this correct?

I get 1.86% for the second calculation - pls check.

There is no such thing as a rolling 2Y1Y IRS (sure you can plot a rate on a chart but you cant trade it).
If on day T, lets call it Monday 18th Nov 2024, you execute a 2Y1Y swap then that swap will have effective date 18th Nov 2026 and termination 18th Nov 2027 (at least in GBP).
On any other day, be it T+1, or whenever, if you want to know the PnL of the instrument you have traded, then you price the instrument that you have traded which is a swap with effective date 18th Nov 2026 and termination 18th Nov 2027 with the fixed rate as specified when you traded the contract, with the curve you have constructed on date T+1 or whenever.
I cannot ascertain any more information that is needed to answer this question.

To be clear, "if you want to know the PnL of the instrument you have traded, then you price the instrument that you have traded which is a swap with effective date 18th Nov 2026 and termination 18th Nov 2027." Isn't what you described above exactly what I've done in my toy example above?

Well if so then what is your question?
